# wordpress get_category_parents doesnt return parents

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a table, with a lot of categories and I use `get_category_parents($cat, false, ' -> ');` to get their parents, but for some of them it doesn't return parents, maybe there should need to be any content in parent category to get returned?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for categories to be displayed they must have content (posts) in the category for it to show on the frontend of your website.

If that still does not fix your problem try this.

```
<?php echo get_category_parents(category, display link, separator, nice name); ?>
```

It will display a list of the parents of a category, including the category, in hierarchical order.